# When rotating an object with the mouse and not using physics the rotating object part of it getting inside the ground plane?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When using physics and rotating the object stay on surface, but when not using physics the object in some times when rotating it half of it get inside the ground (plane).

How to keep the object on the surface when rotating it without physics?

Both the dice cube object and the plane have a box collider component and the dice cube object also have a rigid body.

[image: half of the rotating object is in the ground plane while rotating without physics]

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateDice : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float torque = 50.0f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public bool usePhysics = false;
    public bool isRotating = true;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if ((isRotating))
        {
            if (usePhysics)
            {
                rb.AddTorque(Vector3.up * torque * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));
                rb.AddTorque(Vector3.right * torque * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
            }
            else
            {
                rb.useGravity = false;
                rb.isKinematic = true;
                float rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * torque * Time.deltaTime;
                float rotationY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * torque * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationX);
                transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, rotationY);
            }
        }
    }
}
```